# Macro to return the 'this' pointer, or NULL when it's not available

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Is it possible to access the **this** pointer in non-static context and use something else in static context automatically? Do you know any macro or template magic?

```
#define LOG std::cout << _is_the_this_pointer_available_ ? this : 0

class Foo {
  void test() {
    LOG;
  }
};

void staticTest() {
  LOG;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Macros operate on a level before anything is known about function/class scope, so they won't do it. Also, C++ does not provide any specific feature to detect whether you are in a nonstatic member function or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know any macro or template magic?

Honestly, I wouldn't do this with a macro. When something can be done *without* macros, I'd suggest to prefer avoiding them. Here is a possible solution based on overloading, CRTP, and inheritance (no macros):

```
int get_this() { return 0; }

template<typename T>
struct get_this_helper
{
    T* get_this() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
};
```

The only overhead is that you have to make your classes derive from the proper specialization of `get_this_helper<>`, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG std::cout << get_this() << std::endl;

class Foo : public get_this_helper<Foo> {
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//        This is the only thing that requires 
//        being changed wrt your version of Foo
public:
  void test() {
    LOG;
  }
};

void staticTest() {
  LOG;
}
```

Here is a simple test program:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.test();
    staticTest();
}
```

And a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1XTnBW%2428).

Comment: Unfortunately I would like to make this work without forcing all classes to subclass a helper...

Comment: @LeventeMészáros: There is no standard, portable way of doing that. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Multiple compilers: MS VC, gcc, clang on multiple platforms: windows, linux, mac

Comment: @LeventeMészáros: I might be wrong, but in that case I'm afraid this is as far as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following technique to write *this* pointer to a log:

```
#define GET_THIS() __if_exists(this) { this; } __if_not_exists(this) { nullptr; }
```

However it is Microsoft specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define LOG std::cout << isThisAvailable()

bool isThisAvailable() { return false; }
struct X
{
    bool isThisAvailable() { return true; }

    void test() { LOG; }
};

void staticTest()
{
   LOG;
}
```

Calling `isThisAvailable` inside the class will return `true`. Calling outside the class context will call the free function and return `false`.

Comment: ... but you'd need a function for every class. Also won't compile for a static method inside a class - [test](https://ideone.com/4u3HBU).

Comment: @Dukeling yeah. Too bad :))